# How to apply common JavaScript and CSS for all my jsp pages in the application?

Tags: javascript, css, jsp

I am currently importing all the CSSs and JavaScript sources into each of the JSP pages in the application? How can we make it (apply CSS and JS to all JSPs) in one shot without repeating the code in every JSP?

Thanks,
MouliPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate a portion of the page like header, and put all imports there, then call that separated header to any of your JSP.

Answer (score 1):

I think dividing the *header*, *footer*, *body part* and then adding them to the *master page* will be a good option for further maintenance of application. Call all your `jsp`s inside the body part of *master page* rather than adding *header*, *footer* and all imports in all `jsp`s.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this, in your `web.xml` put this tag

```
<jsp-config> 
  <jsp-property-group> 
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern> 
    <include-prelude>/header.jsp</include-prelude> <!-- use this -->
    <include-coda>/footer.jsp</include-coda> <!-- and/or use this -->
  </jsp-property-group 
</jsp-config>
```

*header.jsp*

```
<!-- put your all css and js imports -->
```

Find more in detail [doc here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/webapp/configurejsp.html#wp159472)